# How to extract feature names from sklearn pipeline transformers?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, pipeline

For reference:

- Python 3.8.3
- sklearn 1.0.2

I have a [`scikit-learn pipeline`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.pipeline.Pipeline.html) that formats some data for me, described below:

I define my `pipeline` like so:

```
# Pipeline 1
cat_selector = make_column_selector(dtype_include=object)
num_selector = make_column_selector(dtype_include=np.number)

cat_linear_processor = OneHotEncoder(handle_unknown="ignore", drop='first', sparse=False)
num_linear_processor = make_pipeline(SimpleImputer(strategy="median", add_indicator=True), MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(-1,1)))

linear_preprocessor = make_column_transformer( (num_linear_processor, num_selector), (cat_linear_processor, cat_selector) )

model_params ={'alpha': 0.0013879181970625643,
 'l1_ratio': 0.9634269882730605,
 'fit_intercept': True,
 'normalize': False,
 'max_iter': 245.69684524349375,
 'tol': 0.01855761485447601,
 'positive': False,
 'selection': 'random'}
model = ElasticNet(**model_params)

pipeline = make_pipeline(linear_preprocessor, model)
```

`pipeline.steps` yields:

```
[('columntransformer',
  ColumnTransformer(transformers=[('pipeline',
                                   Pipeline(steps=[('simpleimputer',
                                                    SimpleImputer(add_indicator=True,
                                                                  strategy='median')),
                                                   ('minmaxscaler',
                                                    MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(-1,
                                                                                1)))]),
                                   <sklearn.compose._column_transformer.make_column_selector object at 0x0000029CA3231EE0>),
                                  ('onehotencoder',
                                   OneHotEncoder(handle_unknown='ignore',
                                                 sparse=False),
                                   <sklearn.compose._column_transformer.make_column_selector object at 0x0000029CA542F040>)])),
 ('elasticnet',
  ElasticNet(alpha=0.0013879181970625643, l1_ratio=0.9634269882730605,
             max_iter=245.69684524349375, normalize=False, selection='random',
             tol=0.01855761485447601))]
```

What I am trying to do is retrieve the feature names for the data that is trained/tested on.

I have tried referencing numerous other questions:

- [Sklearn Pipeline: Get feature names after OneHotEncode In ColumnTransformer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54646709/sklearn-pipeline-get-feature-names-after-onehotencode-in-columntransformer)
- [Can You Consistently Keep Track of Column Labels Using Sklearn's Transformer API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57528350/can-you-consistently-keep-track-of-column-labels-using-sklearns-transformer-api/57534118#57534118)
- [Use ColumnTransformer.get_feature_names to create a reverse feature mapping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58396031/use-columntransformer-get-feature-names-to-create-a-reverse-feature-mapping)

However, these solutions have not worked. For example:

```
[i for i in v.get_feature_names() for k, v in pipeline.named_steps.items() if hasattr(v,'get_feature_names')]
```

Yields:

```
----> 1 [i for i in v.get_feature_names() for k, v in pipeline.named_steps.items() if hasattr(v,'get_feature_names')]

NameError: name 'v' is not defined
```

I tried:

```
pipeline[:-1].get_feature_names_out()
```

Yields:

```
AttributeError: Estimator simpleimputer does not provide get_feature_names_out. Did you mean to call pipeline[:-1].get_feature_names_out()?
```

How can I retrieve feature names after encoding from my current pipeline?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess this post may help:

- [Get feature names after sklearn pipeline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70993316/get-feature-names-after-sklearn-pipeline/71048229#71048229)

Namely, the problem should just be sklearn's version. The PRs referenced in what I posted a couple of months ago seem to have just been merged, though a new release has not been there yet since then. Installing the actual *development version of sklearn*, `scikit-learn 1.1.dev0` should do the trick (it did it for me, at least).

You can install the [nightly builds](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/developers/advanced_installation.html#installing-nightly-builds) as such: `pip install --pre --extra-index https://pypi.anaconda.org/scipy-wheels-nightly/simple scikit-learn -U`.

Here's an example on a *toy* dataset:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder, MinMaxScaler
from sklearn.impute import SimpleImputer
from sklearn.pipeline import make_pipeline
from sklearn.compose import make_column_selector, make_column_transformer
from sklearn.linear_model import ElasticNet

X = pd.DataFrame({'city': ['London', 'London', 'Paris', 'Sallisaw', ''],
              'title': ['His Last Bow', 'How Watson Learned the Trick', 'A Moveable Feast', 'The Grapes of Wrath', 'The Jungle'],
              'expert_rating': [5, 3, 4, 5, 3],
              'user_rating': [4, 5, 4, 2, 3]})

# Pipeline 1
cat_selector = make_column_selector(dtype_include=object)
num_selector = make_column_selector(dtype_include=np.number)

cat_linear_processor = OneHotEncoder(handle_unknown="ignore", drop='first', sparse=False)
num_linear_processor = make_pipeline(SimpleImputer(strategy="median", add_indicator=True), MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(-1,1)))

linear_preprocessor = make_column_transformer( (num_linear_processor, num_selector), (cat_linear_processor, cat_selector) )

model_params ={
    'alpha': 0.0013879181970625643,
    'l1_ratio': 0.9634269882730605,
    'fit_intercept': True,
    'normalize': False,
    'max_iter': 245,
    'tol': 0.01855761485447601,
    'positive': False,
    'selection': 'random'}
model = ElasticNet(**model_params)

pipeline = make_pipeline(linear_preprocessor, model)
pipeline.fit(X.iloc[:, :-1], X.iloc[:, -1])

pipeline[:-1].get_feature_names_out()
```

[image]