# How to access the get_feature_names_out() or columns in a specific transformer in SKlearn's ColumnTransformer?

Tags: scikit-learn

Consider the following ColumnTransformer code:

```py
    tree_preprocessor = ColumnTransformer(
        [
            (
                "categorical",
                OrdinalEncoder(),
                ["region","trade","shipping","payment","channel","device"]
            ),
            
            (
                "numeric",
                "passthrough",
                ["bag_total", "hero_total", "acc_ind"]
            ),
    
            # Custom Function for array hot encoding
            (
                "array_one_hot_encode",
                MultiHotEncoder(df=df_final),
                ["model_list"]
            )
        ],
        remainder="drop",
    )
```

How can I access the features of the `categorical` transformer?

What I'm trying to do is create a DataFrame post `fit_transform()`.

SKLearn does not have `get_feature_names_out()` for all its transformers, so I would like to loop through each transformer in the ColumnTransformer and pull the features post fit (if possible). Otherwise, pull the input feature names out.

For example, because `OrdinalEncoder()` does not have `get_feature_names_out()`, I would like to access the original feature list (`["region","trade","shipping","payment","channel","device"]`)

However, for MultiHotEncoder, I built a custom `get_feature_names_out()` function, so it should definitely work and will return a list of columns post transformation.

Comment: May https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71830448/how-to-extract-feature-names-from-sklearn-pipeline-transformers/71834869#71834869 help?

Comment: I saw that answer as well, but `scikit-learn 1.1.dev0` is definitely not ideal for production